# Scaling JScrollPane with picture

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, graphics2d

I'm new to java and swing:). I need help with scaling JScrollPane when I scaling picture whit method scale :
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.scale(1, 0.3);//I need to scale my picture
When I apply scaling to an image, the JScrollPane does not scale. It's in the  "protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)" method. How can I do that - scaling picture together with IScrollPane. Is't possible? Maybe there is something better for creating java images.
Thank you for any help.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test extends JPanel {  
  public static void main(String... args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                Test test = new Test();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(test);
                frame.add(scrollPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(3000, 3000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.scale(1, 0.3);//I need to scale my picture
        g2.drawLine(30, 30, 30, 3000);
        g2.drawLine(30, 400, 500, 3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can reduce the size of your `JScrollPane` by setting a `JScrollPane` preferred size.  You should also create the image first, then scale it.  The call to the scale method should be last.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: Don't scale the scroll pane. Instead you need to scale the panel. So you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to use the scaling factor. The scaling factor should be defined as an instance variable of your class so it can be used in both methods.